# Как полностью убрать углы у RoundedCornerShape в Jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Мне нужно создать прямоугольник с двумя закругленными сверху углами, пробовал убрать 2 угла у RoundedCornerShape:

```
        Card(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .clip(
                    RoundedCornerShape(
                        topStart = 30.dp,
                        topEnd = 30.dp,
                        bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                        bottomStart = 0.dp,
                    )
                ),
            backgroundColor = light
            ){

            //***
        }
```

Но в итоге скругление убирается не полностью и остаются такие засечки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу их убрать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы убираете углы у маски, но у самого компонента `Card` остаются собственные закругления углов.

Будет правильнее задать компоненту кастомную форму и отказаться от обрезки по контуру:

```kotlin
        Card(
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                topStart = 30.dp,
                topEnd = 30.dp,
                bottomEnd = 0.dp,
                bottomStart = 0.dp,
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            backgroundColor = light
            ){

            //***
        }
```